# using 2d array as indices of a 4d array

Tags: arrays, numpy, pytorch, indices

I have a Numpy 2D array (4000,8000) from a `tensor.max()` operation, that stores the indices of the first dimension of a 4D array (30,4000,8000,3). I need to obtain a (4000,8000,3) array that uses the indices over this set of images and extract the pixels of each position in the 2D max array.

```
A = np.random.randint( 0, 29, (4000,8000), dtype=int)
B = np.random.randint(0,255,(30,4000,8000,3),dtype=np.uint8)

final = np.zeros((B.shape[1],B.shape[2],3))

r = 0
c = 0
for row in A:
  c = 0
  for col in row:
    x = A[r,c]
    final[r,c] = B[x,r,c]
    c=c+1
  r=r+1

print(final.shape)
```

Is there any vectorised way to do that? I am fighting with the RAM usage using loops. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html#numpy.take_along_axis).

First let's create some data (you should have provided a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)):

```
>>> N, H, W, C = 10, 20, 30, 3
>>> arr = np.random.randn(N, H, W, C)
>>> indices = np.random.randint(0, N, size=(H, W))
```

Then, we'll use [`np.take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html#numpy.take_along_axis). But for that the `indices` array must be of the same shape than the `arr` array. So we are using `np.newaxis` to insert axis where shapes don't match.

```
>>> res = np.take_along_axis(arr, indices[np.newaxis, ..., np.newaxis], axis=0)
```

It already gives usable output, but with a singleton dimension on first axis:

```
>>> res.shape
(1, 20, 30, 3)
```

So we can squeeze that:

```
>>> res = np.squeeze(res)

>>> res.shape
(20, 30, 3)
```

And eventually check if the data is as we wanted:

```
>>> np.all(res[0, 0] == arr[indices[0, 0], 0, 0])
True

>>> np.all(res[5, 3] == arr[indices[5, 3], 5, 3])
True
```

Comment: This answer should be accepted. Very helpful